# how to avoid splitting an argument in a variable which contains spaces in double quotes?

Tags: bash

```
$ foo='A="1 2" B=3' sh -c 'ruby -e "p ARGV" $foo'
["A=\"1", "2\"", "B=3"]
```

How do I get `["A=1 2", "B=3"]` instead?

I know that:

```
sh -c 'ruby -e "p ARGV" A="1 2" B=3'
["A=1 2", "B=3"]
```

but the variable `foo` is needed because my real problem is in a "shell execute process" in a Jenkins job.

EDIT: use an array in a same shell

```
$ foo=(A="1 2" B=3) && ruby -e "p ARGV" $foo
["A=1 2", "B=3"]
```

However, array cannot be propagated through as an environment variable...

```
$ foo=(A="1 2" B=3) sh -c 'ruby -e "p ARGV" $foo'
[]
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the space to bridge the chasm caused by the lack of proper quoting.

```
foo='A="1\ 2" B=3' sh -c 'ruby -e "p ARGV" $foo'
```

This is basically a variant of the "don't do that" question. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: thanks for your answer and link to BashFAQ, but the code give me `["A=\"1\\", "2\"", "B=3"]`

Answer (score 2):

We had this exact problem with Jenkins. I.e

./ourScript.py "${args}"

had the args broken on space in spite of the quotes.

We fixed it with

eval "./ourScript.py '${args}'"

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you want to send 2 additional parameters to ruby (`A=1 2` and `B=3`), but inside a single variable (`foo`).  This is not simple as the space in the 1st parameter will be used for word splitting by the subshell.  A solution is to tell the subshell to use another character for word splitting (I am using `_` bellow).  So your script becomes:

```
foo="A=1 2_B=3" sh -c 'IFS=_; ruby -e "p ARGV" $foo'
```

If you want to keep `_` as a possible character in your parameters, you could use a newline for word splitting instead, but it becomes less readable:

```
foo="A=1 2
B=3" sh -c 'IFS="
"; ruby -e "p ARGV" $foo'
```

Comment: Thanks for you let me know the magic variable `IFS`. But, `foo` is given by another system in my case. So, changing the delimiter character isn't suited.

Comment: What do you mean by 'given by another system' ?  If you do not control foo, maybe you can create a foo1 from foo and still use the IFS trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
sh -s 'A=1 2' B=3 <<\EOF
export "$@"
python3 -c 'import os; print("\n".join(os.environ[x] for x in ["A", "B"]))' "$foo"
EOF
```

This requires your `/bin/sh` to support the declaration command behavior of `export` specified by the unreleased POSIX-2008 TC1.

Translate to ruby as I don't use it.

**edit** this doesn't make sense... you want argv or the environment? You cannot pass an array through the environment and you can't have named variables passed through argv.

For argv, don't try using a variable. Pass the strings to the shell wrapper as arguments.

```
$ sh -c $'python3 -c \'import sys; print("\\n".join(sys.argv[1:]))\' "$@"' _ 'A=1 2' B=3
A=1 2
B=3
```

Comment: In my real case, the program takes those parameters is `make`. I used `ruby` to describe the problem in one line. So, either argv or env vars could be OK. Anyway, I'v not understood your intension in your answer. The environment variable `foo` contains parameters `A="1 2" B=3` as a string, not having `A=1 2` and `B=3` as separated arguments nor env variables. I hope I understood your intention.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment in an answer of the question, the program takes those parameters (A and B) is `make`. So, I decided to expand `$(foo)` in a recipe and invoke submake. Because `make` expand variables as is.

BEFORE:

```
$ foo='A="1 2" B=3' sh -c 'make $foo'
```

AFTER:

```
$ foo='A="1 2" B=3' sh -c 'make wrapper'
```

Makefile:

```
wrapper:
    make $(foo)
```

This is not the exact answer to my question, but the solution what I chose.